# Best way to redirect upon form submission using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I know this has been asked and answered before, but I would like to know which of the following is the best way to implement a redirect on form submission.

I have the PHP submission code in a the header section of a webpage. This works fine, but when the form is submitted, the page returns to the same page. If I put a

```
header("Location: page2.php");
```

below the submission code the page immediately redirect to this page (as expected - the code is run as soon as the page loads so it wont even create the form, it will just move on).

Now, do I

1/ Put the code for data submission in a PHP function (together with the redirect code) and then call this function when the form is submitted. This way the function wont run until after the data has been inputted and the same page doesn't have to be reloaded only to redirect to another page almost immediately.

2/ Instead of the function above, use an `if` statement in the header to test one of the pieces of data. That way the submission code is ignored until the form has been filled out and the submit button is pressed. The downside as far as I can see is the same page has to be called to get back to running the code in the header, which can then submit the data and run the redirect code.

3/ Something completely different!

---

### EDIT

This is the code in the header of form.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $user = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $user;

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $phone_number = $_POST['phone'];
    $email_address = $_POST['email'];
    $house = $_POST['add1'];
    $street = $_POST['add2'];
    $town = $_POST['add3'];
    $city = $_POST['add4'];
    $postcode = $_POST['add5'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `first_page_data`(`title`, `first_name`, `surname`, `phone_number`, `email_address`, `house`, `street`, `town`, `city`, `postcode`) VALUES ('$title','$first_name','$surname','$phone_number','$email_address','$house','$street','$town','$city','$postcode')";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $first_data);
    header("Location: newproperty2.php");
}
?>
```

Can this be run on the page that is redirected to, or does it have to be run on the page with the form?

Comment: I think what you want is action attribute to add to html form.

Comment: To call a function, or to direct to another page? If I direct to another page using this the submit code in the initial page isnt run.

Comment: you can use action="rpage.php" to redirect the page to rpage.php to execute rpage.php, it will also have the data collected from the form of previous page.

Comment: Im not getting what you mean, if I redirect to the same page then the code in the head (together with the redirect code) is run the first time its loaded so the form is never shown. If its a redirect to another page then the submission code is never run as it didnt have any data to enter when it first ran and isnt called again after the user has filled the form in.

Comment: I would advise you not to write the php code on that page itself. write it on another page and you can also use the data you got from the form.

Comment: so the $_POST array will still be set and available on the page I redirect to?

Comment: use $_POST[name] and $_POST['email'] to access name and email from the form.It can be retrieved on welcome.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using `action` attribute, look at the code below...

```
    <form action="newproperty2.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br/>
    SURNAME: <input type="text" name="surname"><br/>
    Phone:  <input type="text" name="phone"><br/>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br/>
    title: <input type="text" name="title"><br/>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Here the page is directed to welcome.php after submit button is pressed, moreover you can also access `name` and `email` by using $_POST['name'] and $_POST['email'].
Then put the PHP code above in newproperty2.php(another file). you need not include header(). in that code also add other variable that I didnt wrote here.

Comment: so the $_POST array is still set in the page its redirected to? At the moment Im putting the code for the SQL submission in the header of the form page, and then trying to run that code once the button is pressed, either by calling the same page again or by passing the function name.

Comment: Yes $_POST can be used to retrieve data from the form you filled. can you show me the code and tell what are you actually try to do?

Comment: added to question to give you a bit more insight! (ps dont worry about no sanitization etc, its purely a hypothetical site - it wont be uploaded anywhere!)

Comment: Is the form you are getting the data from on the same page?

Comment: one more thing! If for some reason there is an error with the submitted data, is it correct to redirect to the previous form to re-enter data?

Comment: doesnt having the submit code on a different page tend to get messy and confusing? Would it not be easier to have the code on the same page as the form so its all contained in one file?

Comment: To check for errors in the submitted data you need to put i validations, and yes if the form is having invalid data you should redirect it to the previous page to reenter data.

Comment: Its a good practice to write codes in different files. Actually it gets messy when you put all together. Also, you have to use extra loops and functions in code to avoid getting PHP code executed when page is loading for the first time.